# Understanding the implementation of the $p$-adic(?) sigma function in SageMath

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions, sage

I'm trying to understand the (pretty undocumented) method `.sigma()` method for formal groups of elliptic curves, as listed [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/formal_group.html). The source code looks like this:

```
def sigma(self, prec=10):
    """
    EXAMPLES::

        sage: E = EllipticCurve('14a')
        sage: F = E.formal_group()
        sage: F.sigma(5)
        t + 1/2*t^2 + (1/2*c + 1/3)*t^3 + (3/4*c + 3/4)*t^4 + O(t^5)
    """
    a1,a2,a3,a4,a6 = self.curve().ainvs()

    k = self.curve().base_ring()
    fl = self.log(prec)
    R = rings.PolynomialRing(k,'c'); c = R.gen()
    F = fl.reverse()

    S = rings.LaurentSeriesRing(R,'z')
    c = S(c)
    z = S.gen()
    F = F(z + O(z**prec))
    wp = self.x()(F)
    e2 = 12*c - a1**2 - 4*a2
    g = (1/z**2 - wp + e2/12).power_series()
    h = g.integral().integral()
    sigma_of_z = z.power_series() * h.exp()

    T = rings.PowerSeriesRing(R,'t')
    fl = fl(T.gen()+O(T.gen()**prec))
    sigma_of_t = sigma_of_z(fl)
    return sigma_of_t
```

For context, an elliptic curve object in Sage is specified by an actual Weierstrass form
$$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$$
with paramaters $[a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_6]$, and not just an isomorphism class. The only really important part of the above code is the second to last stanza, as the rest is just converting between the parameter $z$ (from the complex uniformization) and the customary formal group parameter $t=-x/y$.

**Mathematical context**

Anyway, this code is apparently supposed to return some form of the Weierstrass $\sigma$-function, or more accurately I think it's supposed to return something like the $p$-adic $\sigma$-function as studied by Mazur and Tate in their paper of that name (and many others since). Recall that the classical Weierstrass $\sigma$-function satisfies (among many other identities)
$$d(d\log \sigma(z;\Lambda)) = - \wp(z;\Lambda).$$
where $\Lambda$ is the (fixed, for our purposes) auxiliary data of a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$, equivalently a rigidified elliptic curve.

The $p$-adic $\sigma$-function according to Mazur and Tate is usually put in terms of the formal parameter $t$, but for our purposes, we'll just write it in terms of $z$. In that case it can be given by
$$\sigma_p(z;\Lambda) := \exp(-E^{(p)}_2(\Lambda)z^2/24)\sigma(z;\Lambda)$$
where $E^{(p)}$ is the $p$-stabilized Eisenstein series of weight $2$, normalized to have residue $1$ at the cusp at infinity. In particular, by taking the second log derivative of both sides we get $d(d\log\sigma_p(z)) = -\wp -E^{(p)}_2(\Lambda)/12$.

(Compare this to the formula $X-\wp = E^{(p)}_2(\Lambda)/12$ on page 2 of the Mazur-Tate article.)

**The source of my confusion**

The code above *almost*, but not quite, looks like it does this. Indeed, we have the Weierstrass $\wp$-function initialized as its power series in terms of $z$

```
wp = self.x()(F)
```

using the fact that the $x$-coordinate in Weierstrass form is said function. This is followed by this mysterious line:

```
e2 = 12*c - a1**2 - 4*a2
```

which appears to say that we should have something like "$E_2^{(p)}(\Lambda) = 12c -a_1^2-4a_2$" (probably up to a scalar since e2 might be normalized differently), where $c$ is a free variable whose "meaning" is not clear to me.

The rest of the relevant code does this:

```
g = (1/z**2 - wp + e2/12).power_series()
h = g.integral().integral()
sigma_of_z = z.power_series() * h.exp()
```

which is all very much as expected: indeed, if we apply $d\circ d\log$ to the equation in the last line, we get

$$ d(d\log \text{"sigma of z"}(z)) = -\frac{1}{z^2}+ d(d\text{"h"}) = -\frac{1}{z^2}+\text{"g"} = -\wp + \frac{\text{"e2"}}{12}$$

This makes it indeed look like `e2` is some form of $E_2^{(p)}$, but it appears to be off by a factor of $-2$. Could just be a weird normalization, or (as likely) a mistake on my part.

(One thing which suggests that it's not a mistake and in fact is just a different of a factor of $-2$ is that in the case that $a_1=a_2=0$, e.g. reduced Weierstrass form), `c` is then $-\frac{1}{24}E_2^{(p)}$, which is a pretty standard normalization often denoted $G_2^{(p)}$.)

So my question generally is, **what's going on here?** More specifically,

1. Am I correct that this is supposed to be something like the $p$-adic $\sigma$-function? (It has to be somewhat more subtle that that, I guess, since it's not like it can be all of them for different $p$ at the same time, but I'm failing to see how it works.)
2. What's going on with the `e2` variable and its relationship to the `c` variable? What precise relationship is the former supposed to have to $E_2^{(p)}$ as above? What are you supposed to ``plug in'' for `c` to actually get particular values of $\sigma_p$ for different $p$? Can you use this variable to evaluate it at a different rigidification (i.e. choice of invariant differential) without changing the isomorphism class of the elliptic curve? And how does this relate to the weird equation `e2 = 12*c - a1**2 - 4*a2`?

Comment: I fear this is a question for me and not for the forum, though I don't mind if someone else answers it. I doubt I will have time to look into it for a while but I will. Feel free to move it to an email conversation.

Comment: Oh, are you the author of this code? I'll shoot you an email soon!

Comment: Oh, I would never publically admit to be the author of such badly documented code - even if it is 15 years or older. I'll answer by email and will improve the documentation at some point.....

Comment: From a mathematical perspective, the answer to this question is spectacularly boring: This code is outdated, originally used in now deleted code. One should use E.padic_sigma(p) to obtain the canonical sigma function. I will change the function in question and its documentation soon.

Comment: https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/31573 is the ticket that fixes this. It is likely to enter sage for version 9.4.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was started some long time ago, i also tried to understand in some depth the related mathematical structure. Although it may have become obsolete after the comment of [Chris Wuthrich](https://mathoverflow.net/users/5015/chris-wuthrich) to the OP, i completed it and submit it now.

---

Among all related papers delivered by the search engine, the reference that suits closest in notation seems to be:

[MST] :: [*Computation of $p$-Adic Heights and Log Convergence*, Barry Mazur, William Stein, John Tate](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Emazur/preprints/pheight.pdf)

and the notations / relations $(1.4)$, $(1.2)$, $(1.3)$, $(1.5)$, $(1.6)$, $(1.7)$ in [MST] are inserted below for the convenience of the reader and for simpler reference. [MST] is based on an earlier paper, [MT91], The $p$-adic sigma function, Duke Math. J., 62 (1991).

---

We work with the elliptic curve of (affine) equation
$$
\tag{$1.4$}
y^2+a_1xy+a_3 = x^3 + a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6\ .
$$
Let $x(t)$ be the Laurent series of the shape
$$
\tag{$1.2$}
x(t) =\frac 1{t^2}+\dots\in\Bbb Z_p((t))
\ ,
$$
that expresses $x$ in terms of the parameter $t=-x/y$.

---

**(MST) Theorem 1.3:** *There is exactly one odd function
$\sigma(t) = t+\dots \in\Bbb Z_p[[t]]$
and constant $c\in \Bbb Z_p$
that together satisfy the differential equation
$$
\tag{$1.3$}
x(t) +c = −\frac d\omega\left(\frac 1\sigma\;\frac{d\sigma}\omega\right)\ ,
$$
where $\omega$ is the invariant differential
$
dx/(2y+a_1x+a_3)
$
associated with the  Weierstraß equation for E.*

**(MST) Remark 1.4.** *The condition that $\sigma$ is odd and that the coefficient of $t$ is 1 are essential.*

---

Using $x(t)$ as in $(1.2)$ the series
$$
\tag{$1.5$}
\wp(t) = x(t) +\frac 1{12}(a_1^2+4a_2)\in \Bbb Q((t))
$$
satisfies $(\wp')^2=4\wp^3-g_2\wp-g_3$.

Then $(1.6)$ is cited from [MT91] with a sign self-correction:
$$
\tag{$1.6$}
x(t) + c =\wp(t) -\frac 1{12}{\mathbf E}_2(E,\omega)\ .
$$
This leads to (a slightly changed version of $(1.7)$):
$$
\tag{$1.7'$}
12c =(a_1^2+4a_2)-{\mathbf E}_2(E,\omega)\ .
$$

---

The code seems to have notations inspired from the above. Let's see the parallel, if any, best in some *ad-hoc* generic example:

```
prec = 5
A.<a1,a2,a3,a4,a6,c> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
E = EllipticCurve(A, [a1, a2, a3, a4, a6])
EFormalGroup = E.formal_group()
elog = EFormalGroup.log(prec)
eexp = elog.reverse()
S.<z> = LaurentSeriesRing(A)

F = eexp( z + O(z^prec) )
```

This gives the following value for `F`:

```
sage: F
z - 1/2*a1*z^2 + (1/6*a1^2 - 1/3*a2)*z^3 + (-1/24*a1^3 + 1/3*a1*a2 - 1/2*a3)*z^4 + O(z^5)
sage: latex(F)
```

$$
z - \frac{1}{2} a_{1}z^{2} + \left(\frac{1}{6} a_{1}^{2} - \frac{1}{3} a_{2}\right)z^{3} + \left(-\frac{1}{24} a_{1}^{3} + \frac{1}{3} a_{1} a_{2} - \frac{1}{2} a_{3}\right)z^{4} + O(z^{5})
$$

This $F$ or `F` above is the "same one" as in the code, in the line `F = F(z + O(z**prec))`. (My `elog` is the `fl` from the sage code, my `eexp` is the exponential of the formal group, `F = fl.reverse()`.)

Then the code associates the $x$-component, computed in `F`, in the line `wp = self.x()(F)` - and this maps the additive group generator / uniformizer `z` near zero into...

The line `e2 = 12*c - a1**2 - 4*a2` corresponds **up to sign** to the above $(1.7')$, if `e2` is a sort of ${\mathbf E}_2(E,\omega)$. (The sign correction is an other issue...) Then the code considers the power series of the object

```
(1/z**2 - wp + e2/12)
```

I suppose that `wp - e2/12` implements $\wp(t) -\frac 1{12}{\mathbf E}_2(E,\omega)$ from $(1.6)$. We also get rid of the pole $1/z^2$ since we know how to double integrate it, and in the code the double integration should avoid logarithmic terms. So in the code, the RHS of $(1.6)$ is assumed to be the RHS of $(1.3)$, staying for $x(t)+c$, we undo the RHS of $(1.3)$ by double integration and exponentiation so `h = g.integral().integral()` followed by `h.exp()` gets the part in $\sigma$ without the pole contribution in $-1/z^2$. Its double integration, $\log z$, followed by exponentiation, is then inserted as correction in the line `sigma_of_z = z.power_series() * h.exp()`.

We come back by undoing the passage from the aditive formal group to the elliptic curve formal group, i.e. from `z` to `F` (or `eexp`), by plugging in the `fl` (or `elog`).

---

I suppose, the code of the formal group `sigma` method was designed to support some very special experiments for some very special purposes. The above generic curve does not have the method `padic_sigma` from the comment to the OP of [Chris Wuthrich](https://mathoverflow.net/users/5015/chris-wuthrich), but some elliptic curve defined over $\Bbb Q$ has it.
As a final comment, the two methods seem to do different things (even for the same value of the constant $c$). Let us compare.

I will use the prime $p=17$, and the curve `'14a'`.

For the "old code" in the implementation of `sigma` and for the computed value of $c$ plugged in, we have:

```
p = 7
prec = 6
E = EllipticCurve('14a')
FG = E.formal_group()
cval = (E.a1()^2 + 4*E.a2() - E.padic_E2(p)) / 12
for coeff in FG.sigma().coefficients()[:7]:
    print(coeff.subs({c: cval}) + O(p^prec))
```

This gives the first few coefficients in `FG.sigma()`:

```
1 + O(7^6)
4 + 3*7 + 3*7^2 + 3*7^3 + 3*7^4 + 3*7^5 + O(7^6)
6*7 + 2*7^2 + 5*7^3 + 7^4 + 3*7^5 + O(7^6)
2 + 6*7^2 + 2*7^3 + 4*7^4 + 6*7^5 + O(7^6)
2 + 3*7 + 3*7^2 + 7^3 + 2*7^4 + 5*7^5 + O(7^6)
4 + 5*7 + 5*7^2 + 7^3 + 3*7^5 + O(7^6)
3 + 6*7 + 5*7^2 + 3*7^3 + 3*7^4 + 2*7^5 + O(7^6)
```

For the method `padic_sigma` named in the comment of [Chris Wuthrich](https://mathoverflow.net/users/5015/chris-wuthrich) we have an `ArithmeticError: p must be a good ordinary prime` for the code:

```
for coeff in EllipticCurve('14a').padic_sigma(p)[:8]:
    print(coeff + O(p^prec))
```

Using some other prime, $p=13$ for instance instead, we get different results.
The coefficients of `FG.sigma()` are...

```
1 + O(13^6)
7 + 6*13 + 6*13^2 + 6*13^3 + 6*13^4 + 6*13^5 + O(13^6)
2 + 5*13^2 + 6*13^3 + 5*13^4 + 3*13^5 + O(13^6)
10*13 + 10*13^2 + 12*13^3 + 4*13^4 + 8*13^5 + O(13^6)
7*13 + 6*13^3 + 5*13^4 + 13^5 + O(13^6)
10 + 10*13 + 2*13^2 + 2*13^3 + 8*13^4 + 6*13^5 + O(13^6)
5 + 9*13 + 10*13^2 + 10*13^3 + 3*13^4 + 9*13^5 + O(13^6)
```

and on the other side...

```
sage: 
....:     for coeff in EllipticCurve('14a').padic_sigma(p)[:8]:
....:         print(coeff + O(p^prec))
....: 
O(13^6)
1 + O(13^6)
7 + 6*13 + 6*13^2 + 6*13^3 + 6*13^4 + 6*13^5 + O(13^6)
9 + 3*13 + 5*13^2 + 10*13^3 + 4*13^4 + O(13^6)
4 + 2*13 + 11*13^2 + 5*13^3 + 10*13^4 + 3*13^5 + O(13^6)
4 + 7*13 + 13^2 + 6*13^3 + 10*13^4 + 12*13^5 + O(13^6)
8*13 + 11*13^2 + 4*13^3 + 8*13^4 + 5*13^5 + O(13^6)
12 + 2*13 + 13^2 + 5*13^3 + 2*13^4 + O(13^6)
```

The first two coefficients agree, but starting with the term in third degree, the constant $c$ appears effectively:

```
sage: t = FG.sigma().parent().gen()
sage: FG.sigma() + O(t^5)
t + 1/2*t^2 + (1/2*c + 1/3)*t^3 + (3/4*c + 3/4)*t^4 + O(t^5)
```

Comment: In short : If the reduction is good ordinary, use E.padic_sigma(p); it is the unique canonical $p$-adic sigma function in that situation. If the reduction is split multiplicative, there is way to get the square of it from E.tate_curve(p). Ask if needed. The non-split multiplicative case is not implemented. In the supersingular case there is no unique canonical choice. In sage the $p$-adic height is implemented as a function that takes values in the Dieudonne module $D_p(E)$, as Perrin-Riou does it in her work. These are methods of E.padic_lseries(p) for such primes.

Comment: Historic: The method described in the question was used before Mazur-Stein-Tate found a quick way to evaluate E2 using Kedlaya's algorithm. Instead I treated it as a power series with one unknown $c$ and used the fact that the canonical one for an ordinary prime has integer coefficients to determine congruences on the unknown $c$. That code stayed in sage for a while because it also worked for $p=2$ and $3$, while Kedlaya's algorithm wasn't (isn't ?) implemented there for these primes.

Comment: References for the ordinary case: Mazur-Tate The p-adic sigma function. Duke Math. J. 62 (1991), no. 3, 663–688.
For the supersingular case : Perrin-Riou, Bernadette Arithmétique des courbes elliptiques à réduction supersingulière en p Experiment. Math. 12 (2003), no. 2, 155–186. And the older  Bernardi, Dominique; Perrin-Riou, Bernadette Variante p-adique de la conjecture de Birch et Swinnerton-Dyer (le cas supersingulier) C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 317 (1993), no. 3, 227–232..